# How does the "drab office kitchen" look like?

Tags: word-meaning

[**This article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/campaign-trail-storm-british-prime-160020772.html) has such a following passage as ( in 7th ).

> The five-minute broadcast showed Johnson walking through his campaign headquarters, answering questions put to him from behind the camera, greeting staff members, and making a cup of tea in **a drab office kitchen.**

Merriam Webster Unabridged has 5 entries (except for the verb), so that I am afraid I am confused which to pick, so would someone help me kindly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top result on Google is probably the best definition for this usage:

> lacking brightness or interest; drearily dull.

In my experience this is by far the most common meaning of "drab". I've never heard of it used in any relation to prostitutes, so I find it strange that Merriam Webster lists that as the top 2 definitions.